# access denied after clean install of mysql with macports

Tags: mysql, mac-osx

I installed mysql5 and mysql5-server with macports
started service fine
but when i did

mysqladmin5 -u root -p ping

i get

Enter password: 
mysqladmin5: connect to server at 'localhost' failed
error: 'Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO)'

after some rooting around the socket was missing so i did a shameless chmod on its location, restarted and the socket now appears but that doesn't fix my original problem

tried to reset the password (just incase it had been set by the magical password fairies or something) using this technique: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/resetting-permissions.html#resetting-permissions-unix

that did nothing
thought I would have a look at the logs
there was nothing in /opt/local/var/log/mysql5/ but it was empter
did some more chmod 777ing and now  .turd_mysql5-server is appearing but its empty

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what mysqladmin5 is, but I'm guessing it's the same syntax as mysql. If so, your problem is that you're using a space between the -u and the username and the -p and the password. That's why it says "Using password: NO". Try:
`mysqladmin5 -uroot -pping`

Comment: its mysqlamin5 cause i installed with macports which adds the version to the end so you can run multiple version, so yes its exactly the same

Comment: well did my suggestion fix your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I believe only mysql passwords omit the space, as in -pyourpassword. The user name still requires the space.